# Read projects settings from code

Tags: .net, settings, project

We would like to know if it is possible to read values from the projectfile.vbproj.user file or use it to compile values into the binaries.

Comment: The *.user file is an XML file, so you can read it with an XML parser (like the XDocument.Load()). But this is user setting in the file which I would stay away from - what values do you want to get?

Comment: I was more hoping to store a directory value that differs on each developers PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vbproj.user file contains preferences for Visual Studio and doesn't form part of the compiled application.

If you want to extract values from it in this way, you need to parse it during the build and generate a file that is included in your application.

You could consider using a [T4 template](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/30/t4-preprocessed-text-templates-in-visual-studio-2010/) to parse the file and generate a VB class for you.

But consider if it's the right thing to do in the first place. The intent of the file is to persist development-time settings, not runtime ones.